# API for NCAA 2011/12 mens basketball team and player stats

Tags: java, api, statistics, stat

I am looking for an existing API or a method to obtain NCAA Men's Basketball player and team stats.  I have failed to finding anything that is easy to use or up-to-date.  Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to find a API to provide NCAA Mens Basketball data.  I have hacked together the following service that parses data from http://stats.ncaa.org/.

Examples at:
http://ncaa-data-api.appspot.com/

The following services are available.

1. Get all the Division 1 teams in JSON format
2. Get all the players on team in JSON format
3. Get statistics for a specified player in JSON format
4. Get schedule for a team in JSON format

Comment: This appears to be dead?

Comment: No, it works for me. @sholmes, would you mind open-sourcing it? I'm trying to do something very similar for March Madness this year. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is great. Any way to see how it was accomplished? Interested in pulling the play-by-play for games through the API. Thanks

Comment: i wanted to scrape BOX SCORE of all matches and here is how I did it .. 

http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/game/basketball-men/d1/2015/04/06/wisconsin-duke/boxscore.json?callback=ncaaGameTabs.drawTab

Answer (score 0):

I found two interfaces to data.ncaa.com that appear to be more accurate and reliable than ncaa-data-api.appspot.com, and contain more data.  Below are two examples. Replace basketball with your desired sport as well as change the date, game info, and "callback" name...which is really just a label for the data feed.

Individual game detail:
http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/game/basketball-men/d1/2015/04/06/wisconsin-duke/boxscore.json?callback=ncaaGameTabs.drawTab

Daily list of games, including scheduled, in-progress, and complete:
http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2016/01/23/scoreboard.html

In attempting to use ncaa-data-api.appspot.com, I ran into issues of missing teams, away flag being used on both teams if the site was neutral, creating a problem with duplicate data needing to be filtered, and duplicate data in a single feed on multiple calls to the same api function.  Every call resulted in the data feed adding another set of data.

Comment: BTW, anyone know who owns ncaa-data-api.appspot.com?  There are some nice features to it if it could be fixed.

Comment: Does this work for 2019!?